# Cocoa availability on Android

Tags: android, cocoa

Are the Cocoa libraries available on Android? If so, then how can I use them on Android?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. The NeXTSTEP, Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch libraries are proprietary to Apple.

[GNUstep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNUstep) and [OpenStep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStep) are projects that aim to create an open source clone of NeXTSTEP. These will not run on Android natively as far as I know, but since they are open source, you can find the project pages and mailing lists and find out if you can help out in any way. Who knows: Maybe someone else is interested in bringing them to Android?

Comment: OpenStep is not actually a project, this was both a specification and implementation that NeXT created but has since been transformed into modern Cocoa. There is another open source project called Cocotron http://www.cocotron.org that also aims to implement Cocoa in a cross platform fashion.

Answer (score 1):

It's unavailable on Android only for iOs

Comment: Have any other choice instead of cocoas on android?

Comment: The Android NDK is a viable option on Android, if you're willing to target the most recent versions, around Android 2.2 and above, you have access to enough C API to develop apps.

Comment: @ChristopherLloyd Any plans for Cocotron to target Android as well?

Answer (score 0):

Android runs Android SDK.

Check it out here http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html